# Where does dockerized jetty store its logs?

Tags: jetty, docker, dockerfile

I'm packaging a project into a docker jetty image and I'm trying to access the logs, but no logs.

Dockerfile

```
FROM jetty:9.2.10
MAINTAINER Me "me@me.com"

ADD ./target/abc-1.0.0 /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT

EXPOSE 8080
```

Bash script to start docker image:

```
docker pull me/abc
docker stop abc
docker rm abc
docker run --name='abc' -d -p 10908:8080 -v /var/log/abc:/var/log/jetty me/abc:latest
```

The image is running, but I'm not seeing any jetty logs in `/var/log`.

I've tried a `docker run -it jetty bash`, but not seeing any jetty logs in `/var/log` either.

Am I missing a parameter to make jetty output logs or does it output it somewhere other than `/var/log/jetty`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why you aren't seeing logs

2 things to note:

1. Running `docker run -it jetty bash` will start a new container instead of connecting you to your existing daemonized container.
2. And it would invoke bash instead of starting jetty in that container, so it won't help you to get logs from either container.

So this interactive container won't help you in any case.

But also...

#### JettyLogs are disabled anyways

Also, you won't see the logs in the standard location (say, if you tried to use `docker exec` to read the logs, or to get them in a volume), quite simply because the Jetty Docker file is aptly disabling logging entirely.

If you look at the [jetty:9.2.10 Dockerfile](https://github.com/appropriate/docker-jetty/blob/6a38e700ebcff515bc94d2fbe8c1b3fa991f5a92/9.2-jre7/Dockerfile), you will see this line:

```
&& sed -i '/jetty-logging/d' etc/jetty.conf \
```

Which nicely removes the entire line referencing the jetty-logging.xml default logging configuration.

### What to do then?

#### Reading logs with `docker logs`

Docker gives you access to the container's standard output.

After you did this:

```
docker run --name='abc' -d -p 10908:8080 -v /var/log/abc:/var/log/jetty me/abc:latest
```

You can simply do this:

```
docker logs abc
```

And be greeted with somethig similar to this:

```
Running Jetty: 
2015-05-15 13:33:00.729:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2295ms
2015-05-15 13:33:02.035:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting umask=02
2015-05-15 13:33:02.102:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Opened ServerConnector@73ec519{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-05-15 13:33:02.102:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting GID=999
2015-05-15 13:33:02.106:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting UID=999
2015-05-15 13:33:02.133:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.10.v20150310
2015-05-15 13:33:02.170:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/] at interval 1
2015-05-15 13:33:02.218:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@73ec519{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-05-15 13:33:02.219:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3785ms
```

Use `docker help logs` for more details.

#### Customize

Obviously your other option is to revert what the default Dockerfile for jetty is doing, or to create your own dockerized Jetty.

Comment: That's awesome!! What does docker do with the logs? Does it keep all logs or only the latest? On a side note, if I take the existing NGINX docker image, can I make it forward its logs so that docker handles te logs as well?

Comment: about docker logging options, take a look at https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#logging-drivers-log-driver

Comment: What I've eventually done is just to copy the jetty Docker file and remove the line that disables the logs and now I can mount the logs in a volume.
See https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mycee/jetty-with-logs/